# Android BufferedWriter : Empty File Saved.

Tags: java, android, filesystems, bufferedwriter

I am facing a problem and unable to identify it. The case is, I have an activity from which I am saving a JSON file to the storage on some button click. There are times when the file is an empty file(0 KB). So, most of the times it work as expected but this 0 KB file created a headache. There is no exception at all.

Thanks in advance!

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;

try {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
    bw.write(content);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.e(mContext,"Write To File",e.toString());
}
finally {
    try {
        if (bw != null) {
           bw.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.e(mContext,"Write To File",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, one in 1000 times it happens. I had wrote a test case to test this function but couldn't replicate the issue.

Comment: please verify that "content" variable isn't empty in those cases add: 
    Logger.d(mContext,"content",content);
check the logcat when the file is empty

Comment: are you using the exact file else where in your application? maybe somewhere you open the file for writing and truncate the file

Comment: I have a doubt that when the file is being written and suddenly the user forcefully closes the application  then in this case Can the file be empty?

Comment: @Khaledvic : No there is no place where i am writing into the same file.

Comment: @AnkitSingh I think it's extremely unlikely to force close the application in the middle of the short block of code above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it that way:

```
fw = new FileWriter(file, false);
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
...
bw.flush();
bw.close();
fw.close();
```